# I have two lists, I need to pick a random sample from one list, and from the second list pick the corresponding indices

Tags: python, random

I have two lists. One with sample data and one with corresponding labels. I need to randomly pick data from the sample data , but I need their corresponding labels as well.

This is what I currently do:

```py
amount = int(5000 * percent)
rawTrainingData = random.sample(rawTrainingData, amount)
```

Raw training data is my first list. My second list is trainingLabels, but I want it to correspond with the first list.

For example if you have lists as such:

```
['A','B','C','D']
['1','2','3','4']
```

And I wanna pick two random elements from the first list, and have their corresponding indices picked from the second list.

Example:

```
['C','A']
['3','1']

['B','D']
['2','4']
```

Initially both lists are same length and they correspond with each other. I just want them to remain corresponding once I randomize the first array.

Comment: create a zipped list from both lists and pick an element from _that_ list

Comment: for `a` and `b` lists then `list(zip(a, b))` is a zipped list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

zip both lists together, pick an item from the zipped list:

```
import random

a = ['A','B','C','D']
b = ['1','2','3','4']

c = list(zip(a,b))

print(random.choice(c))
```

can output:

```
('A', '1')
('D', '4')
```

"unzip" if you need that. And use `sample` to avoid repeats:

```
list1=[]
list2=[]
for a,b in random.sample(c,2):
    list1.append(a)
    list2.append(b)
```

can output:

```
>>> list1
['B', 'A']
>>> list2
['2', '1']
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up doing this to unzip: unzipped = zip(*zipped)
        rawTrainingData = unzipped[0]
        trainingLabels = unzipped[1]

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
def foo(original, sample):
    return [str(original.index(i) + 1) for i in sample]

foo(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'C'])
```

It will return:

```
['1', '3']
```

Comment: This might not give the desired results if the lists contain duplicates, and it would need modification if the second list weren't just a range of numbers, and doing index-lookup in this way isn't efficient, which could matter a great deal if the actual lists are as large as the machine-learning context would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the commenters are suggesting is

```
j = list(zip(rawTrainingData, trainingLabels)
selected = random.sample(j, amount)
selected_training_data = [td for (td, l) in selected]
selected_labels = [l for (td, l in selected]
```

There are certainly other approaches, but this seems like a good one.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get two lists from two different list, for example a,b

```
import random

a = ['A','B','C','D']
b = ['1','2','3','4']

c,d = zip(*random.sample(list(zip(a,b)),2))
print(c,d)
```

it will return

```
('C', 'A') ('3', '1')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
import numpy as np

def _random_sample(X, y, sample_size):
  data =[(i,j) for i,j in zip(X, y)]
  data_2= random.sample(data, sample_size)
  del data
  
  X1 = []
  y1 = []
  for t in data_2:
   X1.append(t[0])
   y1.append(t[1])
  
  del data_2
  X1 = np.array(X1)
  y1 = np.array(y1)
  return X1, y1


X_train=[ [1,1,1], [2,2,2],  [3,3,3], [4,4,4] ]
y_train =['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

X1, y1 = _random_sample(X_train, y_train, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random       

a = [i for i in range(1,10)]        
b = [i*10 for i in range(1,10)]        

random.seed(110)        
print(random.sample(a,4)    

random.seed(110)        
print(random.sample(b,4))
```

If you set your seed to a fixed value, then the numbers that are generated will be always in the same order.